# Combine specifc rows from multiple csv.'s in nested folders and transpose into a timeseries

Tags: csv, import, directory, nested

My goal is to import specific rows from multiple csv.'s (409) in nested subfolders. Each csv corresponds to rainfall measured over a specific month. In each csv, the rows correspond to rain gage stations at specific locations. Daily rainfall is shown in the columns to the far right in the image below. Because months are of different lengths, the number of columns in each csv file varies.
[example csv of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMkDh.png)

For a given rain gage, I want to extract the appropriate row of data and transform into a new df with a daily timestamp and the amount of rain (station id, lat, long, and elevation could be transformed as well, but are not as important at this point). The objective is to create a df for each rain gage of interest that looks like this: [objective of data import and transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL4yu.png).

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

The following did not achieve what I wanted:

dir("station_data", full.names = T) %>%

df <- map_df(read_csv)bind_rows(lapply(csv_files, read_csv))

Answer (score 0):

If you have in example these two csv files, for two months

```
id,2006.08.01,2006.08.02,2006.08.03
U1,5.69,12.36,8.21
U2,4.69,12.56,9.21
U3,4.69,1.36,82.21
```

```
id,2006.09.01,2006.09.02,2006.09.03
U1,3.69,17.36,8.21
U2,4.69,16.56,2.21
U3,3.69,10.36,182.21
```

you can use this [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/installing-miller/) command

```
mlr --csv filter '$id=="U1"' then reshape -r '[0-9]{4}' -o d,v 01.csv 02.csv
```

to get

| id | d | v |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 2006.08.01 | 5.69 |
| U1 | 2006.08.02 | 12.36 |
| U1 | 2006.08.03 | 8.21 |
| U1 | 2006.09.01 | 3.69 |
| U1 | 2006.09.02 | 17.36 |
| U1 | 2006.09.03 | 8.21 |

Some notes:

- `filter '$id=="U1"'` to filter rain gage "U1"
- `reshape -r '[0-9]{4}' -o d,v` to reshape wide to long all the fields with 4 numbers. `-o d,v` to set the output field names